# How to improve this react-query multiple queries conditionally called code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have a component that takes router urls params and trigger calls depending on these params.

Here's how I made it

```
const {
  data: data1,
  isLoading: isLoading1,
  isError: isError1,
} = useQuery({
  queryKey: [`test-${props.match.params.language}`],
  queryFn: () =>
    fetch(
      `${BASE_URL}${API_URLS.GET_QUIZ}/?languages=${props.match.params.language}&level=${props.match.params.difficulty}`
    ).then((response) => response.json()),
  enabled: props.match.params.source === "api",
});

const {
  data: data2,
  isLoading: isLoading2,
  isError: isError2,
} = useQuery({
  queryKey: [`test-${props.match.params.language}`],
  queryFn: () => {
    console.log("intoQuery");
    return fetch(
      `${BASE_URL}${API_URLS.TEST}/${props.match.params.language}`
    ).then((res) => res.json());
  },
  enabled: props.match.params.source === "intern",
});

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("data2", data2);
  console.log("data1", data1);
  if (props.match.params.source === "api") {
    setData(() => data1);
    setIsloading(isLoading1);
    setIsError(isError1);
  }
  if (props.match.params.source === "intern") {
    setData(() => data2?.questions || []);
    setIsloading(isLoading2);
    setIsError(isError2);
  }
}, [data1, data2]);
```

It works but I find that the code is redundant, and there is much boiterplate.

I would like to know if is possible to optimise it better and only return one `{data, isLoading,IsError}` object instead of having `{data1, isLoading1,IsError1}` and `{data2, isLoading2,IsError2}`

I very simple solution is to conditionally set the url.

But I would like to know it these is other ways

Comment: https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks/issues/120

Comment: Here the queries should be triggered conditionally, and I think it's not the same package , I'm using : @tanstack/react-query

Comment: You overwrite the data in setData with each approach. Better to think about how to separate the two approaches instead of looking to combine queries, as they don't depend on each other. Look for suspend and lazy loading in react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const { data, isLoading, isError } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['test', props.match.params.language, props.match.params.difficulty],
  queryFn: () =>
    fetch(
      `${BASE_URL}${API_URLS.GET_QUIZ}/?languages=${props.match.params.language}&level=${props.match.params.difficulty}`
    ).then((response) => response.json())
});
```

if the props change, so will your query key, and it will trigger a new fetch.

Comment: Hey Tk, great work on TSQ. Is there an article explaining why the shift to using `queryKey` over parameters? This will require a lot of refactoring for some codebases.

Comment: if you are referring to the object syntax `{ queryKey, queryFn, ...options }` over `querykey, queryFn, options`, please see `remove` overloads in the v5 roadmap: https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/4252 please also note that the syntax has always been valid, so you can migrate today, and there is even an eslint rule that is auto fixable that will migrate for you: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/eslint/prefer-query-object-syntax